# why one could seperate time dependence and spatial dependence of E M field into a set of harmonic modes?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, maxwell-equations, dielectric

I was studying dielectric and i came accross the following para which i couldn't understand:

> In general, both E and H are complicated functions of both time and space.
>   Because the Maxwell equations are linear, however, we can separate the time
>   dependence from the spatial dependence by expanding the fields into a set
>   of harmonic modes.

**Photonic Crystals: Molding the Flow of Light ....chap 2.  Electromagnetism in Mixed Dielectric Media**

Comment: I don't understand the limitations of doing so! Any references on the topic?

Comment: Maybe you could point out where is that quote taken from, it will improve the context further. :)